# HTML: open page itself in new window

Tags: html

I want to open HTML page **itself** in a new window.

After clicking at the button I want that page will open in a new window. But I dont want to edit main page where the button is located, but I want to edit that page, which will be opened after clicking.

Is that possible **without** using JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="http://yourLink.com" target="_blank" title="describe link">
```

Do you mean like this?
But edit page opened in new window without script is not possible.

Comment: it will open link after clicking on it in a new window. i want that the page will open itself in a new window. For example: everytime you will try to open "page.html" it will open in a new window.

Comment: <a href ="#" target = "_blank" > 
<a href ="page.html" target = "_blank" >

Answer (score 0):

No, what you want to accomplish is not possible without JavaScript. As @Piszu somewhat answered, you need to define this behavior either though JavaScript or through the `target` attribute of links pointing to it.

I may add as a matter of opinion that the more you try to fight default browser behavior, the more headaches you'll run into. There probably isn't a very good reason to be doing whatever it is that you're trying to accomplish.